# Notation on second order total differential and meaning

Tags: calculus

Suppose we have a function of one variable $x$. Its second derivative will be:

$$\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{df}{dx}\right)$$

If we write:

$$d\left(\frac{df}{dx}\right)=\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}dx$$

we can find the change in the first derivative at two different points. What is the difference if we write:

$$d^2f=\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}dx^2$$

How can I interpret the above relation? Can I interpret it as the difference between the first order differentials at two points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taylor-expanding $f(x+dx)=f+df$ with negligible $dx^2,\,df^2$ gives $df=f^\prime dx$. Similarly (albeit with a requirement we no longer truncate at the second power), $f^\prime(x+dx)=f^\prime+df^\prime$ with $df^\prime=f^{\prime\prime}dx$, reproducing your second equation. In particular,$$d^2f=d(f(x+dx)-f)=df(x+dx)-df$$is a change in $df$. However, I think your third equation makes a different point. If we no longer neglect second-order terms,$$f(x+2dx)=f(x+dx)+df(x+dx)=f+2df+d^2f;$$or, if we halve the change in $x$, thereby halving $df$:$$f(x+dx)=f+df+\tfrac12d^2f.$$Comparing this with a Taylor expansion, $d^2f=f^{\prime\prime}dx^2$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So if I am getting it correct $d^2f$ is the change in $df$'s at two nearby points? Also "If we no longer neglect second-order terms" does this mean that the points must be far enough so the approximation is not linear (otherwise $df$ would be the same at the two points)?

Comment: @Anton That was referring to $df=f^\prime dx+\tfrac12f^{\prime\prime}dx^2+o(dx^2)$, so $dx^2\ne0$.